# I need to match a Text from a block including newline

Tags: regex, newline

I need to match a block of text between two tokens including newline. For example
**START** *This is the test which
I want to extract and a use
for my own purpose* **END**

I want
*This is the test which
I want to extract and a use
for my own purpose*
as my output

Answer (score 0):

```
START (.*?) END
```

should do it in your case.

you can even use lookaround for your case if you dont want match groups :

```
(?<=START ).*?(?= END)
```

the first match group will contain what you need.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/qV9uA4

try this if you have newlines in between :

```
START([\s\S]*?)END
```

Comment: What if I have newline between words.